# How can I use a XMLHttpRequest inside a jQuery autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need Data inside a jQuery autocomplete from a XMLHttpRequest
This is my code for XMLHttpRequest:

```
var jsonRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  jsonRequest.open('GET', path);
  jsonRequest.onload = function(){
     var a = jsonRequest.removeEventListener;
  }; jsonRequest.send();
```

This Code also works but how can I use the var a inside my jQuery autocomplete?

This is the jQuery:

```
$('#tags').autocomplete({
source: function(request, response) {
  var data = a;
  var datamap = data.map(function(i) {
    return {
      label: i.serial + ' - ' + i.mac,
      value: i.serial + ' - ' + i.mac,
      desc: i.cpe_ip
    }
  });
  
  var key = request.term;
  
  datamap = datamap.filter(function(i) {
    return i.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
  });

  response(datamap.slice(0, 15));
},
minLength: 1,
delay: 100
```

});

If I use this with JSON-Data for the var data it works fine. But like this it won't work.

---

Now I have this:

```js
$('#snmcAuto').autocomplete({
   source: function(request, response) {
     var jsonRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
     jsonRequest.open('GET', path);
     jsonRequest.onload = function(data){
       response(JSON.parse(data));
     }; 
     
     var datamap = data.map(function(i) {
      return {
        label: i.serial + ' - ' + i.mac,
        value: i.serial + ' - ' + i.mac,
        desc: i.cpe_ip
      }
    });

     var key = request.term;
      
      datamap = datamap.filter(function(i) {
        return i.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
      });
      
      response(datamap.slice(0, 15));
     jsonRequest.send();
   },
   minLength: 1,
   delay: 100
 });
```

This is the code which works for me and yeah its not the best performance but it's still fast.

```js
 $('#snmcAuto').autocomplete({
         source: function(request, response) {
           
        var jqxhr = $.getJSON( path, function() {
        var data =  jqxhr.responseJSON;
           var datamap = data.map(function(i) {
             return {
               label: i.serial + ' - ' + i.mac,
               value: i.serial + ' - ' + i.mac,
               desc: i.cpe_ip
             }
           });
           var key = request.term;
           
           datamap = datamap.filter(function(i) {
             return i.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
           });
       
           response(datamap.slice(0, 15));
           })
         },
     
       });;
```

Comment: side point: since your're using jquery, jquery's $.ajax() method is quite a lot easier to use than the built-in XMLHttpRequest object. It provides a nicer wrapper around the same functionality.

Comment: @ADyson yeat if try that but how can I get the pure JSON with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the remote datasource (accessed by AJAX) as the source of the autocomplete data you can do something like this. The key thing is that you must return the response to the autocomplete inside the "onload" callback of the AJAX request, so that it has access to the downloaded data. You also have to pass the search term entered by the user to the server via the querystring.

```
$('#tags').autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    var jsonRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    jsonRequest.open('GET', path + "?term=" + request.term);
    jsonRequest.onload = function(data){
      response(JSON.parse(data.responseText));
    }; 
    jsonRequest.send();
  },
  minLength: 1,
  delay: 100
});
```

Comment: thx for ur answer. What u mean by request.term? I can also use just the path to a folder with the data?

Comment: `request.term` is the value supplied by the autocomplete plugin. It represents what the user typed. It's discussed in the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source)

Comment: "I can also use just the path to a folder with the data" ...not in a real-world application, no. You need to use a URL. And server-side code needs to run which will filter the dataset according to what the user typed and only return the relevant results. (well actually, you _could_ return all the results from the server and then process them in the JavaScript before you give them back to the autocomplete, but it would be very inefficient if the dataset has more than a few rows in it)

Comment: So in my case, I have a folder with some JSON Files in there. And the JSON Files get a rndm Name at Login and the var "path" is like "FolderName/userdata.json"  *I edit the Question with my "new" Code

Comment: You need to remove all the client-side static data code from your new version, like I did

Comment: So just ur Code?

Comment: Anyway like I said,  you can use static JSON as the remote data source if you like, but you'll have to write JS code to filter it, and it's not recommended as it's very inefficient to keep downloading all that data when 90% or more of it will not be shown to the user each time. What a waste of bandwidth. You could use caching to mitigate it, but it's still not a great solution.

Comment: As for the specific error message you mentioned, I think maybe I made a slight mistake - see my updated code. I don't use XMLHTtpRequest usually because the jQuery version is much nicer. You can always check the MDN documentation for it yourself to make sure it's implemented as designed.

Comment: What would be the best solution?

Comment: Yes just my code. I removed it for a reason - you have replaced all that stuff by fetching the data from the remote server. If you didn't understand that then I worry that you don't actually understand what the different lines in your own code are actually doing? That's never a good situation to find yourself in.

Comment: Best solution would be filtering the data server side, as I mentioned before. Then only the results which actually match the search are transmitted back to the browser. You can use any server side language your webserver can integrate with, e.g. PHP, node.js, asp net, whatever, it's up to you.

Comment: But the Data is already downloaded on the server so i just filter the data on the server. And yes I have not that much experience in js/jquery but I cant learn the whole language bc. of time

Comment: I don't understand you. The data on the server in the static JSON is not yet filtered by what the user is typing right now. One way or another you have to write code to filter it. And the data is on the server, it is not yet downloaded to the browser.

Comment: I could make it now with the new new code. I know its not the best performence but it work for the moment like this. But thx for ur help. And maybe I make it later more efficiently.

Comment: Ok that's fair enough. If the answer helped you with that then please consider marking it as accepted, thanks :-). Good luck with the rest of it